# Complex queries with SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table with 3 columns "ID", "NAME" & "STATUS". I would like to execute a query on my database where I can get only one entry of "ID" which is located at the top row. I have a working sql query,

`"SELECT TOP 1 ID from SAMPLE_TABLE WHERE Status='PENDING' ORDER BY ID ASC;"`

This is so far what I implemented in android,

```
// Getting pending items
        public int pendingContact() {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor mCount = db.query(
                    TABLE_CONTACTS ,
                    new String[] { "id" } ,
                    "status = ?" ,
                    new String[] { "PENDING" } ,
                    null ,
                    null ,
                    null 
                );

            mCount.moveToFirst();
            int count = mCount.getInt(0);
            mCount.close();

            return count;
        }
```

Al through it gives the desired output but I would like to know if there is any other way of doing this more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Limit`

> public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
>
> limit - Limits the number of rows returned by the query, formatted as LIMIT clause. Passing null denotes no LIMIT clause.

You can do this:

`Cursor mCount = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { "id" }, "status = ?", new String[] { "PENDING" }, null, null, "id ASC", "1");`

This will keep you from acquiring more data than you need.

Comment: The working query does. Without sorting, the result would be random.

Comment: There is ORDER BY ID ASC.

Comment: Haha yeah thanks for continually driving the point through. His code does not, but I didn't try to re-read the non-Android query. :) Thanks CL.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ORDER BY, the database will read and sort all `PENDING` items before it can return the first one.

When using MIN, nothing but the smallest value must be stored temporarily:

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM Contacts WHERE Status = 'PENDING'
```

In code:

```java
Cursor mCount = db.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(id) FROM Contacts WHERE Status = ?",
                            new String[] { "PENDING" });
```